# Multivalue row count in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, multivalue

Input:

```
col1
a,b
a,c
```

Output:

```
col1   count
a      2
b      1
c      1
```

I want to simply count multivalue rows in MySQL Query.

Comment: What is your DB?

Comment: You would need to tell us which _version_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres).  But in any case, note that storing CSV in your SQL tables is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If your "table" is a large table or view, then you can use `cross join` to generate the rows with only one table reference:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then col1 else col2 end) as col,
       count(*)
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
group by col;
```